# Firma usando OpenSSL

Tags: c++, openssl

Ando trabajando con un firmado de cadenas de texto usando ceritifcacos hechos con OpenSSL.

Los pruebo en dos codigos, uno en Java y otro en C++.

No habia tenido problema alguno al firmar con llaves de diferentes tamaños, sin embargo al usar una de tamaño 4096, en Java no me da ningun problema con la firma, cosa que en C++ si..

Alguna idea del que podria ser?

Anexo el texto a firmar y el resultado.

C++:

```
std::string text = "MENSAJEAFIRMAR";
```

Input:

```
QUNj0guStS/KmrDbcJE5Zq/SvjAZYSCcbfjBZf1zuk/Qo2lhqZTf4jGCL6Td8f9AhXf969l5nIet4E8u5NKHBX6IJdCSvAN2V4nzssg4zytHtEY7D1JUr836R5LYuxo5CTk4fzSssT2Dpk8Z0tPib3fVK4sSHw9y15ItkXprB9dOgFETyPve+9tF4GwtctNBfjnZQo48Huh0Ewk00WGgOvgXGA3tNyJ3yWGFmusW0re4dHwqGyQ9W5YCMtPndFTF85sITfR5LssT933yvNkYVHMftlXtR7NXsE6s8U/Az9lqCiLQIDQJmG6zyNlhNxOe7nKZMq7iBaoiOnmAxbmzFD6KLB3DxcKpTYxL8e1pLZW3x0X5qMAWyMTUabK/EeLFTbpKsszWQcYPUXZAtqUDk1mtvjgifwZg7kvlCUBV4dx0cTmBfGSJoKVOZ3ZkVmba8adbnymTD/DieVwWFXGHQppHT8v5ztM9F8T3S0LP3LHlfcZ3gSvWnYTI7/xAsWjJP/5IpfRZXk3E1MNsK1ULeNSiWaxlH/hMfSe6Fvb3qyRYtzpzK05IzXWpNPcR2b+sXJ8uM+uMLaltBtP7eszMa2C5ova6MBX5PsB6qewa8UPmkD2/1Dhs9vre/4+0o4AC3SGnho/VzTGw8wSDp7x3EMaCyNsa9+Yyfkyu2nnZ9ko=��ae�Ld*&�|l▒z�I�-��2
  e@g�ҡ�s�Ǣ1�=j=��*��\�"�F~���g�T����
a�                                       uǩ,}���W%t'���|ժL
�i��/�?� Wu��N�HpyJ���"
```

Java:

```
String sMensajeAFirmar = "MENSAJEAFIRMAR";
```

Input:

```
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
```

Comment: Teniendo en cuenta que no conocemos el cifrado, ni conocemos de qué manera estás cifrando, ni qué librería has usado, ni qué clave has usado: no podremos ayudarte si tenemos más dudas que tú. ¿no podrías compartir el código que estás usando, las cabeceras que utilizaste y la versión de las mismas?

Comment: @Paula_plus_plus la librería es openssl... sobre el resto todo son incógnitas

Answer (score 0):

Podría ser desde el encoding de la información, los caracteres de relleno, el algoritmo, pero como comentan en la repuesta anterior... si pudieras compartir un fragmento de código o información más detallada seria posible acercarnos a una posible ayuda.